# Extracting tokens from a line of text

Tags: bash, grep, text-processing, sed, awk

Using bash scripting and grep/awk/sed, how can I  split a line matching a known pattern with a single character delimiter into an array, e.g.  convert `token1;token2;token3;token4` into `a[0] = token1` … `a[3]=token4` ?

Comment: You answer yourself with the question tags: sed, awk, regex :)

Comment: Please specify a programming / scripting language in which you prefer the answer.

Comment: @Patkos - bash scripting + grep/awk/sed , whichever works best...

Comment: Unclear: It is unclear whether `a[0]`, `a[1]` etc. refers to an array in the shell or in `awk`.

Answer (score 8):

**UPDATE** Please note that making an array this way is suitable only when IFS is a single non-whitespace character **and** there are no multiple-consecutive delimiters in the data string.
For a way around this issue, and a similar solution, go to this [Unix & Linux question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7904/can-ifs-internal-field-separator-function-as-a-single-seperator-for-multiple-co/7949#7949) ... (and it is worth the read just to get more of an insight into IFS.

---

Use bash (and other POSIX shells, e.g. ash, ksh, zsh)'s `IFS` (Internal Field Seperator).

Using IFS avoids an external call, and it simply allows for embeded spaces.

```
# ==============
  A='token0:token1:token2.y   token2.z '
  echo normal. $A
# Save IFS; Change IFS to ":" 
  SFI=$IFS; IFS=:     ##### This is the important bit part 1a 
  set -f              ##### ... and part 1b: disable globbing
  echo changed $A
  B=($A)  ### this is now parsed at :  (not at the default IFS whitespace) 
  echo B...... $B
  echo B[0]... ${B[0]}
  echo B[1]... ${B[1]}
  echo B[2]... ${B[2]}
  echo B[@]... ${B[@]}
# Reset the original IFS
  IFS=$SFI             ##### Important bit part 2a
  set +f               ##### ... and part 2b
  echo normal. $A

# Output
normal. token0:token1:token2.y token2.z
changed token0 token1 token2.y   token2.z 
B...... token0
B[0]... token0
B[1]... token1
B[2]... token2.y   token2.z 
B[@]... token0 token1 token2.y   token2.z 
normal. token0:token1:token2.y token2.z
```

Comment: Do NOT underestimate the importance of "Important bit part 2". I've seen extraordinarily hard to debug problems arise from getting Important bit part 2 wrong.

Comment: @Gilles: Your mod to the code (`set -f`, `set +f`) puzzles me; I don't see the connection between field seperators and globbing, but I'm happy to learn.. I am even more puzzled by the fact that when I introduce `"  *  "` to the first line, I get globbing of `echo normal. $A` which is the normal expectation.. However what has me completely baffled is that I get **no globbing** in any of the present lines when IFS=; This applies whether globbing is on or off..  And with globbing off  in the same block, a new line  `echo *` does expand!.. What's going on here? Globing *and* no globbing together.

Comment: @fred.bear: It's not about separators, it's about unprotected variable substitution (`$A`). Two things happen to `$A`: [field splitting](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_05) (on `IFS`) and [pathname expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_06) (globbing). Compare `sh -c 'set -f; echo $0' '/*'` with `sh -c 'echo $0' '/*'`. I don't know what precise command has you confused, post a standalone example if you want me to look at it.

Comment: You really got me thinking this time!... and I've finally worked it out! ... The *seemingly* eratic behaviour I observed comes from "observational habit" (If it looks like a duck, quacks like a duck, and walks like a duck, it's a duck! ... however all bets are off with *space* (the duck) when IFS=: ... the *space* may still be used by *people* as a visual delimiter, but globbing sees it only as just another character, and globbing needs a delimiter!... So `echo *` will expand "normally", but `A=' *'`;echo $A` will only expand for a file whose name has a leading space...  Mystery unravelled! ;)

Comment: PS... but I still don't see why I need to turn globbing off... (must go now.. I'll think about it as I drive... and read your reference links later...

Comment: @Gilles: If I'm  wrong here, please let me know... (To glob or not to glob; that is the question) ... The anser is "Turn it off!", in all cases, unless you specifically and quite intentionally need it... As I've just found out, IFS can be deceptive because of its unusual/unfamiliar behaviour...  I was focusing my question about globbing to the specific data in this example (which won't glob)... but now I'm a convert... globbing **off** (in the vast majority of cases)...

Answer (score 3):

There are major two approaches. One is `IFS`, [demonstrated by fred.bear](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7827/extracting-tokens-from-a-line-of-text/7832#7832). This has the advantage of not requiring a separate process, but it can be tricky to get right when your input might have characters that have special meaning to the shell. The other approach is to use a text processing utility. Field splitting is built into `awk`.

```
input="token1;token2;token3;token4"
awk -vinput="$input" 'BEGIN {
    count = split(input, a, ";");
    print "first field: " a[1];
    print "second: field" a[2];
    print "number of fields: " count;
    exit;
}'
```

Awk is particularly appropriate when processing multiple inputs.

```
command_producing_semicolon_separated_data |
awk -F ';' '{
    print "first field: " $1;
    print "second field: " $2;
    print "number of fields: " NF;
}'
```

Comment: There's a suggested code change pending here; I'll let you approve/reject it

Answer (score 0):

```
$ str="token1;token2;token3;token4"
$ echo $str
token1;token2;token3;token4
$ echo $str | tr ';' ' '
token1 token2 token3 token4
$ arr=( $(echo $str | tr ';' ' ') ) # Populate the tokens into an array
$ echo ${arr[0]}  # Access items by index
token1
$ echo ${arr[2]}
token3
$ echo ${arr[1]}
token2
$ echo ${#arr[@]}  # Length of the array
4
```

Comment: What do you do if token2 contains a whitespace?

Comment: In that case you better take the approach as **fred.bear** has suggested. However, please remember to restore your `IFS` to the original value in that case.